# How to use the XAML dictionary that Syncfusion Metro Studio produces

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary, syncfusion

For resolution independence we want scaling art. Ok, so a common source for that mentioned on stack is Syncfusion Metro Studio.

Metro Studio 2 produces this for XAML:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Viewbox x:Key="error">
    <Grid Width="64" Height="64" Visibility="Visible">
      <Grid Visibility="Visible">
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFD21818" Visibility="Visible" />
        <Ellipse Fill="#FFD21818" Visibility="Collapsed" />
        <Path Data="M50.5,4.7500001C25.232973,4.75 4.75,25.232973 4.7500001,50.5 4.75,75.767029 25.232973,96.25 50.5,96.25 75.767029,96.25 96.25,75.767029 96.25,50.5 96.25,25.232973 75.767029,4.75 50.5,4.7500001z M50.5,0C78.390381,0 101,22.609621 101,50.5 101,78.390381 78.390381,101 50.5,101 22.609621,101 0,78.390381 0,50.5 0,22.609621 22.609621,0 50.5,0z" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFD21818" Visibility="Collapsed" />
      </Grid>
      <Path Data="F1M54.0573,47.8776L38.1771,31.9974 54.0547,16.1198C55.7604,14.4141 55.7604,11.6511 54.0573,9.94531 52.3516,8.23962 49.5859,8.23962 47.8802,9.94531L32.0026,25.8229 16.1224,9.94531C14.4167,8.23962 11.6511,8.23962 9.94794,9.94531 8.24219,11.6511 8.24219,14.4141 9.94794,16.1198L25.8255,32 9.94794,47.8776C8.24219,49.5834 8.24219,52.3477 9.94794,54.0534 11.6511,55.7572 14.4167,55.7585 16.1224,54.0534L32.0026,38.1745 47.8802,54.0534C49.5859,55.7585 52.3516,55.7572 54.0573,54.0534 55.7604,52.3477 55.763,49.5834 54.0573,47.8776z" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Width="36" Height="36" Margin="0,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Path.RenderTransform>
          <TransformGroup>
            <TransformGroup.Children>
              <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
              <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
            </TransformGroup.Children>
          </TransformGroup>
        </Path.RenderTransform>
      </Path>
    </Grid>
  </Viewbox>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

So far so good, just merge this into the project resources. But how to consume this?

[using viewbox in ResourceDictionary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17566131/using-viewbox-in-resourcedictionary-file) has an answer that lets you change the ViewBox to DataTemplate in the ResourceDictionary and then use a converter to display it as a button's ContentTemplate. That is ok for Button based stuff, but what if I just need the icon itself. How do I go from ViewBox in a resource dictionary to somehow including it in lets say a grid in XAML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a similar thing in one of my projects using Syncfusion Metro Studio. I found wrapping the image in a `ViewBox` caused a number of annoyances. I ended up using the image alone, and then embedded it into a `Path` where I wanted to use the image.

I found it a lot more flexible than trying to squeeze a `ViewBox` into xaml.

How I did it:

There is a type [`Geometry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometry.aspx), which allows you to define a Bezier path as a resource:

```
<Geometry x:Key="Keyboard">M48.537998,24.254L57.365002,24.254 57.365002,30.875 48.537998,30.875z M17.642,24.254L46.332001,24.254 46.332001,30.875 17.642,30.875z M6.6760006,24.254L15.504,24.254 15.504,30.875 6.6760006,30.875z M50.744999,15.426L57.365002,15.426 57.365002,22.047001 50.744999,22.047001z M41.986,15.426L48.606998,15.426 48.606998,22.047001 41.986,22.047001z M33.09,15.426L39.709999,15.426 39.709999,22.047001 33.09,22.047001z M24.261999,15.426L30.882999,15.426 30.882999,22.047001 24.261999,22.047001z M15.435,15.426L22.056,15.426 22.056,22.047001 15.435,22.047001z M6.6070004,15.426L13.229,15.426 13.229,22.047001 6.6070004,22.047001z M50.744999,6.599L57.365002,6.599 57.365002,13.219 50.744999,13.219z M41.986,6.599L48.606998,6.599 48.606998,13.219 41.986,13.219z M33.09,6.599L39.709999,6.599 39.709999,13.219 33.09,13.219z M24.261999,6.599L30.882999,6.599 30.882999,13.219 24.261999,13.219z M15.435,6.599L22.056,6.599 22.056,13.219 15.435,13.219z M6.6070004,6.599L13.229,6.599 13.229,13.219 6.6070004,13.219z M4.47015,4.4635506L4.47015,33.242199 59.6413,33.242199 59.6413,4.4635506z M1.3333101,0L62.666698,0C63.403,0,64,0.59634399,64,1.3333397L64,36.166698C64,36.903702,63.403,37.5,62.666698,37.5L1.3333101,37.5C0.59704602,37.5,0,36.903702,0,36.166698L0,1.3333397C0,0.59634399,0.59704602,0,1.3333101,0z</Geometry>
```

Once you have a geometry resource you can use it in `Path.Data`. In this example the border is the bounds of the image 32x32 pixels. Then you can use the `Border` and use it in a `Grid` as you would with any other control.

```
<Border Width="32" Height="32">
    <Path Data="{StaticResource Keyboard}" Fill="White" Stretch="Uniform" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
    </Path>
</Border>
```

This technique also allows you to bind the properties as needed. I.e. `Fill` to a color, and have it change dynamically.

Comment: This looks like a good approach and I will try it out. It also avoids all the cruft they leave in their xaml (unused box and or circle background etc.)

Comment: I haven't tested how accurate the images are when using a large scaling factor. I imagine they lose a bit of "sharpness", but are pretty close (much closer than a scaled PNG)

Comment: Just tested the scaling, and it's very good. Scaled a 32x32 origin path to "fullscreen", and there is very little (hardly noticeable) aliasing.

Answer (score 5):

You can use it as Content for any ContentControl Directly,in case if you just want the icon in Grid,try like below,

```
 <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Viewbox x:Key="error">
    <Grid Width="64" Height="64" Visibility="Visible">
      <Grid Visibility="Visible">
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFD21818" Visibility="Visible" />
        <Ellipse Fill="#FFD21818" Visibility="Collapsed" />
        <Path Data="M50.5,4.7500001C25.232973,4.75 4.75,25.232973 4.7500001,50.5 4.75,75.767029 25.232973,96.25 50.5,96.25 75.767029,96.25 96.25,75.767029 96.25,50.5 96.25,25.232973 75.767029,4.75 50.5,4.7500001z M50.5,0C78.390381,0 101,22.609621 101,50.5 101,78.390381 78.390381,101 50.5,101 22.609621,101 0,78.390381 0,50.5 0,22.609621 22.609621,0 50.5,0z" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFD21818" Visibility="Collapsed" />
      </Grid>
      <Path Data="F1M54.0573,47.8776L38.1771,31.9974 54.0547,16.1198C55.7604,14.4141 55.7604,11.6511 54.0573,9.94531 52.3516,8.23962 49.5859,8.23962 47.8802,9.94531L32.0026,25.8229 16.1224,9.94531C14.4167,8.23962 11.6511,8.23962 9.94794,9.94531 8.24219,11.6511 8.24219,14.4141 9.94794,16.1198L25.8255,32 9.94794,47.8776C8.24219,49.5834 8.24219,52.3477 9.94794,54.0534 11.6511,55.7572 14.4167,55.7585 16.1224,54.0534L32.0026,38.1745 47.8802,54.0534C49.5859,55.7585 52.3516,55.7572 54.0573,54.0534 55.7604,52.3477 55.763,49.5834 54.0573,47.8776z" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Width="36" Height="36" Margin="0,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Path.RenderTransform>
          <TransformGroup>
            <TransformGroup.Children>
              <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
              <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
            </TransformGroup.Children>
          </TransformGroup>
        </Path.RenderTransform>
      </Path>
    </Grid>
  </Viewbox>
</ResourceDictionary>


<Grid>
  <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource error}"/>
</Grid>
```

if you are intend to use the same resource in multiple location,please set x:Shared attribute as false as below,

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
      <Viewbox x:shared="false" x:Key="error">
         .......
      </Viewbox>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Heh, can only have one answer. This is perfect for using them as is. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Simply import the output from Metro Studio into Expression Blend 
-> Design View

Select icon and click 'Tools' -> Make Brush Resource -> MakeDrawingBrush

Then Blend will convert the icon for use anywhere in your app

Comment: Now this is some next level stuff. Next time I need to do this I will no doubt have to search for the answer again and will try out your solution.